# Check if a path is a folder or a file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which goes through a list of values which are folder or file paths, and delete the files first, then remove the empty folders.

My script so far:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path h:\List_Files.resp.xml
$Files =  XmlDocument.OUTPUT.databrowse_BrowseResponse.browseResult.dataResultSet.Path
```

Now I'm trying to test each line in the variable to see if it's a file and delete it first, and then go through and remove subfolders and folders. This is just so that it's a clean process.

I can't quite get this next bit to work, but I think I need something like:

```
foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    if (! $_.PSIsContainer)
    {
        Remove-Item $_.FullName}
    }
}
```

The next section can clean up the subfolders and folders.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use $file instead of $_ in your loop.

Answer (score 51):

I found a workaround for this question: use `Test-Path` cmdlet with the parameter `-PathType` equal to `Leaf` for checking if it is a file or `Container` for checking if it is a folder:

```
# Check if file (works with files with and without extension)
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Demo\FileWithExtension.txt' -PathType Leaf
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Demo\FileWithoutExtension' -PathType Leaf
 
# Check if folder
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Demo' -PathType Container
```

[image: Demo]

I originally found the solution [here](http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-118-test-if-path-is-a-file-or-a-folder-using-test-path-cmdlet/). And the official reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6).

Comment: this is a totally **disaster** answer, "Container" and "Leaf" worries about regkeys not being dir or file !!!

Comment: as [@muhammad-murad-haider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110840/6791254) sais the only proper way is `(get-item "C:\somefolder").PSIsContainer`

Comment: @TechDogLoverORkiaNasirzadeh The docs for Test-Path seem to indicate that it should work and it works fine on my machine.  Can you provide an example of it producing an incorrect result?

Answer (score 11):

We can use `get-item` command and supply the path. Then you can check `PSIsContainer` (boolean) property that would determine whether the supplied path targets a folder or a file. e.g.

```
$target = get-item "C:\somefolder" # or "C:\somefolder\somefile.txt"
if($target.PSIsContainer) {
# it's a folder
}
else { #its a file }
```

Hope this helps any future visitors.

Answer (score 6):

I think that your `$Files` object is an array of strings:

```
PS D:\PShell> $Files | ForEach-Object {"{0} {1}" -f $_.Gettype(), $_}
System.String D:\PShell\SO
System.String D:\PShell\SU
System.String D:\PShell\test with spaces
System.String D:\PShell\tests
System.String D:\PShell\addF7.ps1
System.String D:\PShell\cliparser.ps1
```

Unfortunately, the `PSIsContainer` property cannot be found on a *string* object but on a *filesystem* object, e.g.

```
PS D:\PShell> Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {"{0} {1}" -f $_.Gettype(), $_}
System.IO.DirectoryInfo SO
System.IO.DirectoryInfo SU
System.IO.DirectoryInfo test with spaces
System.IO.DirectoryInfo tests
System.IO.FileInfo addF7.ps1
System.IO.FileInfo cliparser.ps1
```

To get a filesystem object from a string:

```
PS D:\PShell> $Files | ForEach-Object {"{0} {1}" -f (Get-Item $_).Gettype(), $_}
System.IO.DirectoryInfo D:\PShell\SO
System.IO.DirectoryInfo D:\PShell\SU
System.IO.DirectoryInfo D:\PShell\test with spaces
System.IO.DirectoryInfo D:\PShell\tests
System.IO.FileInfo D:\PShell\addF7.ps1
System.IO.FileInfo D:\PShell\cliparser.ps1
```

Try next code snippet:

```
$Files | ForEach-Object 
  {
    $file = Get-Item $_               ### string to a filesystem object
    if ( -not $file.PSIsContainer)
        {
            Remove-Item $file}
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following code:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:Temp

foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    $_.FullName
}

$Files | ForEach {
    $_.FullName
}
```

The first foreach is a PowerShell language command for looping, and the second ForEach is an alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet which is something completely different.

In the `ForEach-Object`, the `$_` points to the current object in the loop, as piped in from the `$Files` collection, but in the first foreach, `$_` has no meaning.

In the foreach loop use the loop variable `$file`:

```
foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    $file.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way is by using **`DirectoryInfo`**.

MWE from the file-name:

```
$(Get-Item c:\windows\system32) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
```